# Generate Case Classes from Schema and Parse JSON

Tags: json, scala, parsing, schema, jsonschema

I have the json schema:

```
{
    "type ": "record ",
    "name ": "JSONSchema",
    "namespace ": "com.jsonschema ",
    "fields ": [{
            "name ": "schema ",
            "type ": "string "
        },
        {
            "name ": "body ",
            "type ": {
                "type ": "record ",
                "name ": "BodyFinal ",
                "fields ": [{
                        "name ": "schema ",
                        "type ": "string "
                    },
                    {
                        "name ": "data ",
                        "type ": {
                            "type ": "array ",
                            "items ": {
                                "type ": "record ",
                                "name ": "DataFinal ",
                                "fields ": [{
                                        "name ": "tna ",
                                        "type ": [
                                            "null ",
                                            "string "
                                        ],
                                        "default ": null
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name ": "aid ",
                                        "type ": [
                                            "null ",
                                            "string "
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i generate the case classes automatically using schema as:

```
case class JSONSchema(schema: String, body: BodyFinal)
case class BodyFinal(schema: String,data: List[DataFinal])
case class DataFinal(tna: Option[String], aid: Option[String])
```

And then can write a parser to validate the any json received using the case classes. So that if I change the schema in future and add/remove any fields in it then the case classes can be generated and validated against the JSON.

Comment: What have you tried (code)? What are errors (traces)? Which libs?

Comment: Have you considered vice versa approach: generate json-schema from the case classes? I'm asking, because quick googling shows that there is solution for this, like: https://github.com/andyglow/scala-jsonschema . Or you have to use schema from some third party source?

Comment: The JSON you show in your question is not a JSON Schema. It may be "A schema in JSON", but it's not a JSON Schema. It may look like one, but it is not. Did you make this or was it provided to you?

Comment: That should be fairly easy, start by reading that JSON into model classes and then use [scalameta](https://scalameta.org/) to generate Scala code using those models.

Comment: You need this UI tool to generate case classes from complex JSON schemas: https://cchandurkar.github.io/case-class-generator/